# can the_excerpt function also get images?

Tags: post-thumbnails, excerpt

Not sure if im going about this in the right way but, overall, ive been told to create, kind of like a news box on my home page and so, the "latest news" is going to be this clients posts.

now i know i can control `the_excerpts();` content length etc but, i cant seem to find any way for it to also allow an image.

when i showed the client the "news box" he wants whatever image is associated with the post, to come through.

so i thought of `"the_content();"` but i dont think thats what i need(though im not sure which one will work best with what i need)

so the main questions here for me are

1. Can i somhow get the image to come through with the excerpt, or
2. If the excerpt function doesnt allow it, then what can i use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that your Theme supports [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails), and that the client sets a "Featured Image" for each post. Then, combine [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) with [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), e.g. like so:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <div class="featured-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
        <div class="post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

    </div>
    <?php

endwhile; endif;
?>
```

Then, just use CSS to style according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `get_the_post_thumbnail()`?  You can read more about it on the [Codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).  It pulls a thumbnail of the post's featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your functions.php file:

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'preserve_excerpt_format');
function preserve_excerpt_format($text)
{
    global $post;
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ('' == $text )
    {
        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = strip_shortcodes($text);
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

        $exceptions = '<p>,<a>,<em>,<strong>,<br><img>'; //PRESERVE THESE TAGS, ADD/REMOVE AS NEEDED
        $text = strip_tags($text, $exceptions);

        $maxCount = 55; //DEFAULT WP WORD COUNT, INCREASE AS NEEDED
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $maxCount);

        $moreText = '.... <a class="blue" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More &gt;&gt;</a>'; //CUSTOM MORE TEXT, CHANGE AS NEEDED
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', $moreText);

        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length+1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if(count($words) > $excerpt_length)
        {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text.$excerpt_more;
        }
        else
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
```

This should preserve any images that occur within the content's HTML before the Word Limit is reached.